# How to read weblog file using URLExtract Get unique URL using python

Tags: python

Beginner Python.. I have a large log file

how to read and get the log file URL only and I am trying to get only certain URLs like (https, http, :443, :80)
Because some log file indexes are different, how to read certain fields correctly from different lines

How to get unique URL results? I tried a unique URL, but can not get a unique URL

Sample log file format:

```
60.80.94.184    anonymous   Moz/2.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_0 like Mac OS X) Apple/65.1.90 (HTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E Safari/604.1 2012-06-22  03:43:51    -   60.80.17.54 8090    0   781 9843    SSL-tunnel  -   qs.rtoas.zp:80  Upstream    0   0x3 Allowed
180.81.82.170   anonymous   iPad1,3/09.1.1 (16q0)   2012-06-24  04:53:57    -   90.80.97.54 8070    47  217 8440    http    GET http://init-p0.pu.apple.com/bag?v=9 Upstream    200 0x400   Allowed
109.13.61.195   anonymous   clo/76.119 Network/95.0.3 Dain/1.2.0    2012-06-25  09:43:54    -   190.22.19.94    8220    0   517 5057    SSL-tunnel  -   eree-022.opt-2.icloud-content.com:443   Upstream    0   0x8 Allowed
20.81.82.110    anonymous   iPad1,1/09.1.1 (46q5)   2012-06-27  14:53:57    -   40.10.27.54 8070    47  217 8440    http    GET https://qwe-pu.uoras.com/bag?v=19   Upstream    200 x00 Allowed
```

code:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract
files = "WEB_000.w3c"
with open(files, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in f:
        lines = i.strip()
        extractor = URLExtract()
        urls = extractor.find_urls(lines, only_unique=True)
        li = list(set())
        for wa in urls:
            li.append(wa)
        for se in li:
            print(se)
```

Comment: What you want? Please specify your question

Comment: Ok i'm working on it i'm help you simple question.

Comment: Hey @warezers can you make a google conference for this. I need understand full question what are you looking? If is it possible please let me know.

Comment: @Suman google conference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the urlextract will extract unique URL only from the text in `lines` variable. But you are appending everything together and if multiple lines have same URL you have it multiple times.

If order of URLs is not an issue and you just want to have them unique then try this:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract

files = "WEB_000.w3c"
extractor = URLExtract()
urls_unique = set()
with open(files, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        urls = extractor.find_urls(lines, only_unique=True)
        urls_unique |= set(urls)
print(urls_unique)
```

Comment: It shows this error
`AttributeError: 'IPv4Address' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: OK, sorry about that. This is already reported bug in urlextract. I will fix it as soon as I have little bit of free time.

Comment: It should be fixed in latest release (0.13.0) of urlextract.

Comment: Do you think you could give me the line where it fails? I would try to fix it. Could you please add comment to the issue https://github.com/lipoja/URLExtract/issues/41